# LEMP + Wordpress Setup Failing

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, nginx

Hey Guys I'm trying to install wordpress to a subdirectory in my website. I have installed wordpress various times and I have run through the complete proceess of installing mysql, creating the db, changing the wp-config file and installing php.

However when I go to http://site.com/blog it fails to load and instead downloads a file.

I know that nginx is serving the files, but I'm pretty sure PHP is not executing it even though php is running and I have installed all relevant libraries.

Please help! Thanks :)

Nginx sites-available/default file:

```
server {
    listen 80;  
    server_name www.site.com;

    index index.html index.htm index.php;
    root /home/site/;
}
```

Checked if PHP is working:

```
sudo service php5-fpm start
start: Job is already running: php5-fpm
```

Not really sure what else to try...

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell nginx to proxy your PHP request back to php-fpm. See [this](http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2011/nginx-and-php-fpm-configuration-and-optimizing-tips-and-tricks/).

**Excerpt:**

```
# Pass PHP scripts to PHP-FPM
location ~* \.php$ {
  fastcgi_index   index.php;
  fastcgi_pass    127.0.0.1:9000;
  #fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
  include         fastcgi_params;
  fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
  fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
}
```